# Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, webview, react-native-webview

After upgrading react native from 0.61.2 to 0.68.2 with RN update helper, gradle cant build app. Getting this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-webview:compileDebugKotlin'.

> java.io.IOException: Permission denied

trying all react-native-webview versions but result is same.

when i removeing "react-native-webview": "^8.0.3" this line from package.json file then build successfully goes but app getting error because this dependency used in app

below dependency versions which i using.

1. "react": "17.0.2",
2. "react-native": "0.68.2",
3. "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
4. "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
5. "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
6. "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
7. "eslint": "^7.32.0",

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip

android/build.gralde

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android build failure with different errors without any changes in code for past days due to publish of React Native version 0.71.0-rc.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334162/react-native-android-build-failure-with-different-errors-without-any-changes-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running this command on the android folder.

sudo ./gradlew compileDebugKotlin

This worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

**If you face the issue from Nov 4th 2022,**

**Fix for react-native >= 0.63 and lower than 0.67**

In `android/buld.gradle` file,

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    // ...
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
+       exclusiveContent {
+           // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
+           // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
+           // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
+           // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
+           filter {
+               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
+           }
+           forRepository {
+               maven {
+                   // NOTE: if you are in a monorepo, you may have "$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
+                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
+               }
+           }
+       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

What this fix will do is apply an exclusiveContent resolution rule that will force the resolution of React Native Android library, to use the one inside node_modules.

Once you update your app to React Native v0.71.0, this fix won't be needed anymore.

**Fix for older react-native (< 0.63)**

The fix above only works on gradle 6.2 and higher. Older react-native used older gradle.

You may determine your gradle version by looking in your [/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties) file.

If you are on older react-native (for example 0.63 or earlier) that uses gradle version 6.1 or below, you must use a different workaround, detailed here: [#35210 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#issuecomment-1304536693)

***Updated On Nov 11th 2022***

If the above solution is not working for you then try this one.

In `android/buld.gradle` file,

```js
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd been having the same issue since Nov. 4th and fixed it using your suggestion. Thank you. It was turning into a nightmare. 
Do you have any idea why is this happening though?

Comment: @AminDannak, See the details here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Answer (score 4):

In `android/buld.gradle` file you have to specify `kotlinVersion` to "1.6.0"

```
buildscript {
ext {
     //... other fields
    kotlinVersion = "1.6.0" //1 <- here is solution
    RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion //2 <- here is solution
}
dependencies {
    // kotlinVersion you have defined above dot this to koltin version // solution next line
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")//3 <- here is solution
   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use in your project then remove it by uninstall lib not only from package.json

```
npm uninstall react-native-webview
```

If you want to use then, Please Update it to latest version of it:

```
"react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
```

**For ios:**

delete pods and reinstall pods

```
cd ios && pod install
```

**For Android:**
delete build and rebuild it

Hope it works!

Comment: not working with latest version ((
same error

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2593#issuecomment-1177897997

Comment: Not working facing same error

Comment: use the latest stable version 12.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Upgarding your react native version can work
0.63.x to 0.63.5
0.65.x to 0.65.3
0.66.x to 0.66.5
0.68.x to 0.68.5
0.69.x to 0.69.7
0.70.x to 0.70.5

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below setting inside android/build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin (be sure to add version
        // 2.0.0 or later if you built your app with Android Studio 4.1).
//         classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'

//          classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    // NOTE: if you are in a monorepo, you may have "$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android"
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../../../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using react-native version 0.64.0, then based on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210) issue, I upgraded to 0.64.4 and everything is fine now.

this is the useful part of the issue's solution:

> Patches for >= 0.63 We have prepared releases for all the main
> versions of react-native with an hotfix:
>
> 0.70.5:
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.70.5 ️
> 0.69.7: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.69.7  0.68.5:
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.68.5 ️
> 0.67.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.67.5 ️ 0.66.5:
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.66.5 ️
> 0.65.3: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.65.3 ️ 0.64.4:
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.64.4 ️
> 0.63.5: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.63.5
>
> By updating to these patch versions, your Android build should start
> working again.
>
> To do so, in your package.json change react-native's version to the
> relevant new patch (ex. if you are on 0.64.3, change to 0.64.4) and
> run yarn install. No other changes should be necessary, but you might
> want to clean your android artifacts with a cd android && ./gradlew
> clean before trying to re-run your Android app.